# Custom tabular editable data with Autocomplete

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, autofill

I have a tabular data in a form. It should be editable and each field should auto complete.

What is the best way to implement? Should i use Django's forms? Or I have to create my own view with JQuery autofill?

Any pointers is appreciated.

Comment: Forms, views and javascript aren't alternatives to each other. You will always need a view to assemble the data, you will most likely use forms to display the data and you will use javascript/jquery to augment the experience (with autofill). This isn't a real question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [django-ajax-selects](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects). To support tabular inlines, i made a little class:

```
class AjaxTabularInline(admin.TabularInline):
    def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        autoselect_fields_check_can_add(self.form, self.model, request.user)
        return super(AddressInline, self).get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)
```